# Reactjs random colour picker - wow there must be an easier way?

Tags: reactjs

i've build a simple app that lets you click on coloured dots and change each of their colours randomly, also supplying the rgb code. Im a react beginner so just playing around to get an idea.

I got it working, but my code is so long and the opposite of dry! And I know there must be a way to package all those eventhandlers into one...

Thanks in advance for helping me dry out my code and learn...

**APP.JS**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './friedhead.svg';
import './App.css';
import Colour from './Colour/Colour';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
  a1: 138, a2: 131, a3: 198,
  b1: 1, b2: 131, b3: 198,
  c1: 138, c2: 131, c3: 3,
  d1: 138, d2: 12, d3: 198
 }


colourCreator = () => {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * 250) + 1 
}


//wow there must be a better way to do this

updateAHandler = ( event ) => {
  this.setState( {
  a1: this.colourCreator(), a2: this.colourCreator(), a3: this.colourCreator()
  })
}

updateBHandler = ( event ) => {
  this.setState( {
  b1: this.colourCreator(), b2: this.colourCreator(), b3: this.colourCreator()
  })
}

updateCHandler = ( event ) => {
  this.setState( {
  c1: this.colourCreator(), c2: this.colourCreator(), c3: this.colourCreator()
  })
}

updateDHandler = ( event ) => {
  this.setState( {
  d1: this.colourCreator(), d2: this.colourCreator(), d3: this.colourCreator()
  })
}

//wow there must be a better way to do this


  render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">

      <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1>30 days of React</h1>
          <h2>Day Three / Random Colour Picker</h2>
      </header>


      <div className="container">
        <Colour
          clicked={this.updateAHandler}
          c1={this.state.a1.toString()}
          c2={this.state.a2.toString()}
          c3={this.state.a3.toString()}
          id={'a'}
        />

        <Colour
          clicked={this.updateBHandler}
          c1={this.state.b1.toString()}
          c2={this.state.b2.toString()}
          c3={this.state.b3.toString()}
          id={'b'}

        />
      </div>


      <div className="container">
        <Colour
          clicked={this.updateCHandler}
          c1={this.state.c1.toString()}
          c2={this.state.c2.toString()}
          c3={this.state.c3.toString()}
          id={'c'}
        />

        <Colour
          clicked={this.updateDHandler}
          c1={this.state.d1.toString()}
          c2={this.state.d2.toString()}
          c3={this.state.d3.toString()}
          id={'d'}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**COLOUR.JS**

```
import React from 'react';

const colour = ( props ) => {

  let newColour = ("rgb(" + props.c1 +", "+ props.c2 +", "+ props.c3 +")");

  const outputstyle = {
    textAlign: 'center',
  fontSize: 'calc(5px + 2vmin)',
  color: 'black',
  paddingTop: '10vw'
  };

  const divstyle = {
  margin: '20px',
  backgroundColor: newColour,
  textAlign: 'center',
  width: '30vw',
  height: '30vw',
  borderRadius: '100%',
  display: 'inline-block'
  };


 return (

    <div style={divstyle}
         onClick={props.clicked}>
      <h1 style={outputstyle}>{newColour}</h1>
    </div>

  );
};

export default colour;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to improve your code would be like so:

```
updateHandler(container){
  const newState = {}
  newState[container + "1"] = this.colourCreator()
  newState[container + "2"] = this.colourCreator()
  newState[container + "3"] = this.colourCreator()
  this.setState(newState)
}
```

....

```
<Colour
      clicked={() => this.updateHandler("c")}
      c1={this.state.c1.toString()}
      c2={this.state.c2.toString()}
      c3={this.state.c3.toString()}
      id={'c'}
    />
```

This way you only have one handler function for each container.

There is a lot more you could improve here. How about posting this to the codereview stackexchange?

Comment: Ah great thanks @ThatBrianDude - I didn't know there was such a platform for a code review. And thanks for your suggestions, ill dig into those now so I understand them.